# Bindings are undefined when trying to open uib modal Instance

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

We are using angular version 1.5.10 and ui-router version 0.3.1. We are componentify our controller and services.

When we are trying to open modal pop up using `$uibModal.open` method. It is opening the template of the component in the modal pop up. But it is not showing any of the data passed to the controller opened in the modal, using `resolve`

project Component from where we have to call is as follows -

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

export let ProjectComponent = {
    selector: 'ProjectDetails',
    templateUrl: 'app/entities/project-details/project-details.html',
    bindings: {},
    controller: ProjectController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
};

ProjectController.$inject = ['project', '$http', '$scope', '$filter', '$uibModal', 'Record'];

function ProjectController(project, $http, $scope, $filter, $uibModal, Record) {

var vm = this;
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    template: '<project-task-details $resolve="$resolve" ></project-task-details>',
    backdrop: 'static',
    windowClass: 'viewerModal style-1',
    size: 'lg',
    resolve: {
        data: function() {
            return project.getTaskDetails({
                projectId: projectId
            });
        }
    }
  });
}    

angular
    .module('projectApp')
    .component(ProjectComponent.selector, ProjectComponent);
```

Project Service which is using from this Project component -

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
class project {
    constructor($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
    }

    getTaskDetails(params) {
        return this.$http.get('api/project' + '/' + params.projectId).success((response) => response.data);
    }

}
angular
    .module('projectApp')
    .service('project', project);

project.$inject = ['$http'];
export default project;
```

Now the page content which we are trying to load i.e. ProjectTaskDetailComponent:-

```
import angular from 'angular';

export let ProjectTaskDetailComponent = {
    selector: "projectTaskDetails",
    templateUrl: 'app/entities/project-details/project-task-details.html',
    bindings: {
        //  modalInstance: '<',
        data: '<'
    },
    controller: ProjectTaskDetailController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
};


ProjectTaskDetailController.$inject = [];

function ProjectTaskDetailController() {

    var vm = this;
    vm.$onInit = function() {
        vm.projectDetail = this.data;
    }
    // vm.projectDetail = data;
    vm.clear = clear;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#loadingImg').css('display', 'none');
    }, 1000);

    function clear() {

        // $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
}

angular
    .module('projectApp')
    .component(ProjectTaskDetailComponent.selector, ProjectTaskDetailComponent);
```

I tried to open modal pop up which is opened without data. When we debug the code, the data in bindings is undefined in ProjectTaskdetailComponent when in template we pass as `data = "$resolve.data"`. If we use `$resolve = "$resolve"` in template, still data is undefined while we check in ProjectTaskdetailComponent.

Also tried all bindings like `data: "<", data: "=", data: "@"`, but the same issue persists i.e. data is undefined.

Also tried to update the angular-ui-router to 0.4.2 version but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `component` instead of `template` in your `uibModal.open`.

From the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal):

> component (Type: string, Example: myComponent) - A string reference to the component to be rendered that is registered with Angular's compiler. If using a directive, the directive must have restrict: 'E' and a template or templateUrl set.
>
> It supports these bindings:
>
> close - A method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result. The result must be passed in this format: {$value: myResult}
>
> dismiss - A method that can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a result. The result must be passed in this format: {$value: myRejectedResult}
>
> modalInstance - The modal instance. This is the same $uibModalInstance injectable found when using controller.
>
> resolve - An object of the modal resolve values. See UI Router resolves for details.

So in your case, it might look something like:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    component: 'projectTaskDetails',
    backdrop: 'static',
    windowClass: 'viewerModal style-1',
    size: 'lg',
    resolve: {
        data: function() {
            return project.getTaskDetails({
                projectId: projectId
            });
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Edit: Your component bindings will need to conform to their api, so it should look like:

```
export let ProjectTaskDetailComponent = {
    selector: "projectTaskDetails",
    templateUrl: 'app/entities/project-details/project-task-details.html',
    bindings: {
        modalInstance: '<',
        resolve: '<'
    },
    controller: ProjectTaskDetailController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
};
```